# How to change blockreward to 100 cake tokens in pancakeswap

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, uniswap, defi, pancakeswap

Does anyone know how we can set the block reward to **100 cake tokens** in **pancakeswap**. I don't understand which variable will be changed. These are the variables in the migrations file

```
const INITIAL_MINT = '25000';
const BLOCKS_PER_HOUR = (3600 / 3) // 3sec Block Time
const TOKENS_PER_BLOCK = '10';
const BLOCKS_PER_DAY = 24 * BLOCKS_PER_HOUR
const TIMELOCK_DELAY_SECS = (3600 * 6);
const STARTING_BLOCK = 4853714;
const REWARDS_START = String(STARTING_BLOCK + (BLOCKS_PER_HOUR * 6))
const FARM_FEE_ACCOUNT = myaddress
```

and this is how I deploy the masterchef

```
 console.log(`Deploying _masterchef on Testnet`)
       // const rew = BigNumber.from(TOKENS_PER_BLOCK).mul(BigNumber.from(String(10 ** 18)));
      
        console.log('Current block reward ',rew);
        return deployer.deploy(_masterchef,
            CakeToken.address,
            SyrupBar.address,
            myaddress,
            BigNumber.from(TOKENS_PER_BLOCK).mul(BigNumber.from(String(10 ** 18))),
            0,

        )
```

On running the code the **rew** variable returns
`BigNumber { _hex: '0x8ac7230489e80000', _isBigNumber: true }`
which I dont know how to read. So what do I have to change to make it 100, only the tokens per block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0x8ac7230489e80000` is hex, which is 10000000000000000000 (10 ether in int when converted from Wei), so if you change `TOKENS_PER_BLOCK` to `100`, you should get reward per block set to 100 ( in ether unit) and output should be hex in Wei unit.

```
(TOKENS_PER_BLOCK).mul(BigNumber.from(String(10 ** 18))
```

performs conversion to Wei from int value of TOKENS_PER_BLOCK in migrations file.